# java.util.NoSuchElementException: no Line found from the Java Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am creating a quiz game which has one Player instance that the user can create once and then edit the username in Java. My issue comes with my use of the Scanner (I'm pretty sure) which for some reason does not find a new line to read from. My code gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        at Player.setUsername(Player.java:33)
        at Quiz.printPlayerEditor(Quiz.java:118)
        at Run.main(Run.java:20)
```

Here is the method setUsername within Player.java that gives error, this is then used in another method printPlayerEditor from Quiz.java, which is then used in the main (Run.java):

```java
public void setUsername(Scanner in) {
    String user = "";

    do {
        while (!in.hasNextLine() && !user.isEmpty() && user.length() < 16 ) {
            Quiz.printError();
            in.next();
        }
        user = in.nextLine(); //Line 33
        username = user;
        Quiz.setProperties("playerusername", username);

    }while(!username.equals(user));
}
```

The Quiz.java code that gives error (which uses the previous method)

```java
public void printPlayerEditor(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Player editor:");
    System.out.println("Your current username is | " + player.getUsername() + " |");
    System.out.println("Please enter a new username between 1-16 characters:");
    System.out.println("<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>");

    player.setUsername(in);

    System.out.println("Your username is now | " + player.getUsername() + " |\n");
}
```

And then lastly this is used in the main in a switch case that deals with the input. This is where the Scanner comes from:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
        Player player = new Player();

        quiz.setPlayer(player);
        quiz.populateQuestions();
        int input = quiz.printMenu1();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        switch (input) {                
            case 1:
                if (Quiz.getProperties("playerusername").isEmpty()) {
                    quiz.printPlayerCreator(in);
                    input = 2;
                } else {
                    quiz.printPlayerEditor(in);
                    input = 2;
                }
                
            case 2: 
                try {
                    quiz.printUnitMenu(in);

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    quiz.printPlayerCreator(in);
                
                }
                break;

            default:
                Quiz.printError();
                quiz.printMenu1();
                break;
        }

        in.close();
        
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the same scanner into all of them, and I've tried making the classes static and stuff, but I'm still quite new to Java and cannot get my head around why this error may be occurring.

Comment: Do not catch NullPointerException. Add null checks

Comment: How are you running your application? It sounds like your application doesn't have a valid System.in (i.e. it's closed), which can happen sometimes when running from an IDE.

Comment: It seems that the issue was the scanner getting closed in quiz.printMenu1, I would've never found this while reading over as I spent hours trying to fix this code so thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not ever close resources that you aren't responsible for. You are not responsible for `System.in` (in fact, you should never close that unless you really know what that means and are sure you want to do that), and 'wrapper' resources (Such as `Scanner`, generally created with `new ResourceThing(refToSomeOtherResource)`), if you close them, close the thing you wrapped. In other words - don't.

Some linting tools tell you that you should be closing a resource. Those linting tools are incorrect. (somewhat understandably, keeping track of filters 'through' the resource they wrap is a bit complex).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had forgotten to remove a close() which is what caused the issue. May I ask why exactly the linting tools call this a 'Resource leak'?

Comment: Because it incorrectly thinks that `Scanner` represents a resource (it does not, but there are slightly incorrect but somewhat useful reasons to consider them resources), and notices you created it and aren't closing it.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... My issue comes with my use of the Scanner (I'm pretty sure) which for some reason does not find a new line to read from. ..."*

Yes, the *[hasNextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine())* method isn't what you're looking for.

Just loop on *[nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())*, and check whether it meets the requirements.

```java
public void setUsername(Scanner in) {
    String user;
    boolean exit = false;
    do {
        user = in.nextLine();
        if (!user.isEmpty() && user.length() < 16) exit = true;
        else Quiz.printError();
    } while (!exit);
    username = user;
    Quiz.setProperties("playerusername", username);
}
```

Comment: Hey, just tried your suggestion but it still gives the same error while using in.nextLine(). I have tried a few ways of doing the validation but none really seem to change the result, giving the same exception on that line.

Comment: @Sharky, are you closing any other _Scanner_ which uses the _System.in_?